# How to persist values of delegated fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I currently have the following models:

**user.rb**

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
      before_create :build_profile 
    end
```

**profile.rb**

```
    class Profile < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user  
      delegate :name, :email, :name=, :email=, to: :user
    end
```

For the profile, I have the following controller:

**profile_controller.rb**

```
    class ProfileController < ApplicationController

      before_action :set_user
      before_action :authenticate_user!

      def edit
        @user = current_user
        @profile = @user.profile
      end

      def update
        @user = current_user
        @profile = @user.profile

        if @profile.update(profile_params)
          redirect_to profile_path(current_user.username)
        else
          render :edit
        end
      end

      private

      def profile_params
         params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :email, :user_id, :bio, :avatar, :remove_avatar) 
      end

    end
```

My "Edit Profile" form is as follows:

**edit.html.haml**

```
    = simple_form_for @profile do |f|
      = f.error_notification
      .form-inputs
        .row
          .col-md-6.col-sm-12
            = f.input :name, required: true, placeholder: "Name"
          .col-md-6.col-sm-12
            = f.input :email, required: true, placeholder: "Email"
        = f.input :bio, required: true, hint: "Write a short bio about yourself", placeholder: "PHP Developer developing cool apps in Tokyo."
        = f.input :avatar, as: :attachment, direct: true, presigned: true
      .form-actions
        = f.button :submit, "Update", class: "btn ban-info"
```

I am trying to change the delegated values in the profile form. However, they do not persist to the database. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of delegate, which is normally reserved for exposing public methods that do not involve persistence, try adding the following line to your profile model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user #This will allow you to handle user attributes via a profile object
```

Also, in your `update` action you need to specify the relationship of profiles and users such as:

```
if @user.profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
```